# Animal crossing mortgage for your house?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Who do you have to pay? A little confused

Answer (score 1):

You can pay off your mortgage at the ATM in the town hall, it's 10,000 bells for your house. After that it gets more expensive.